# SLURM - echo output file so it prints on screen?

Tags: linux, unix, server, echo, slurm

Our company's server uses a SLURM workload manager.  I'm using `sbatch` to submit a script.  Currently, I have the output printed to a file using `#SBATCH -o /job_%j.out` and `#SBATCH -e /job_%j.err`.  I'd like the `-e` file to print on-screen in addition to printing to the file.  I want to be able to track the progress in realtime without constantly having to open and refresh the `.out` and `.err`files.

I've tried `echo`, but this only results in information being printed to the `-o` file.  I've also tried not specifying a location for the output to print to (ie: no `#SBATCH -o` command), hoping it would default to print to the screen. That didn't work either.

I feel like there is an easy fix, but I clearly not googling the right terms.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 11):

`sbatch` will submit a batch job, running on another computer than the one on which you have a terminal open. Therefore `sbatch` redirects the stdout and stderr to a file. The simplest option is to use `tail -f` to view the contents of the file dynamically.

Otherwise, use `srun` rather `sbatch` to have the output redirected directly on the terminal, but then it is not running in batch anymore and your job will be killed if you loose your connection or if you shut down your laptop or close your terminal window.

Comment: Should `tail -f` display the `print` statements?

Comment: `tail -f` will display whatever is written to the file. But beware that there might be buffers here and there (language runtime buffer, operating system buffer, filesystem buffer, etc.) that might delay things a bit or even a lot)

Answer (score 4):

`watch -n 1 cat my_out_file.out` will print the contents of the file every second.

Answer (score 1):

If your sbatch file contains srun commands, you can use `sattach jobid.stepid` to view the output - you can specify an option to view the error instead of the output.

Comment: I get an "Invalid job id specified" error even though the id is the same as that output by squeue, any hints?

Comment: Just noticed, does sattach only work for srun commands? It would seem that way, I was using it with sbatch.

Answer (score 0):

Once, I had exactly the same problem. An interesting case is, when you are training an ill-posed machine learning model and you can make decision when to stop the training based on the realtime loss.

I wanted to see the output in realtime, but the `.out` file is hard to locate because I already had 100 `.out` files.

SLURM provides you with the interactive sessions. You need to allocate yourself resources using `salloc`.

```bash
salloc --nodes=1 --account=scw1901 --partition=accel_ai_mig --gres=gpu:2
```

Modify this command as per your wish. Then run this command to open a shell directly in the compute node.

```bash
srun --pty bash
```

Now you need to copy everything from the `sbatch` job file after the job allocation.

For example, if this is my `sbatch` script.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes 1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 5
#SBATCH --time 03:00:00
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --job-name jupyter-lab
#SBATCH -o /home/s.1915438/jupyter_log/jupyter-lab-%J.log
#SBATCH -e /home/s.1915438/jupyter_log/jupyter-lab-%J.log
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --account=scw1901
#SBATCH --partition=accel_ai

# run jupyter notebook
module load anaconda/3
source activate ml
```

I will run this script file or just execute these commands after entering in the compute node's shell.

```bash
module load anaconda/3
source activate ml
```

Now, you can run a file and see the outputs. This is the answer to your question.

```bash
python file.py
```

Alternatively, you can save the output and view it using `tail`.

```bash
pwd # copy the output
python file.py >> output.txt
```

Open another ssh session and navigate to the directory using the copied `pwd`. Then use the `tail -n` command to view last few line or `cat` to view the whole file.

Another possibility is to run a port forwarded Jupyter lab. Then you can create multiple ssh connections also jupyter-lab will automatically navigate to the `pwd` in newer versions.